# Is it possible to upgrade VPS on the fly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vps

I know that my question might be slightly off but I'll try anyway...

I've started an EC2 instance that is rather basic `t2.micro`

The software I'm running is using 99% CPU and I really need to upgrade.

I don't seem to find an option in the UI to upgrade my machine and I'm prepared to scrape this on and start fresh.

Before I do this:

- does Amazon offer upgrading VPS on the fly?
- is there any other cloud provider with such feature?
- is it theoretically possible?

*(in case I'm missing something totally obvious please show me how upgrade my `t2.micro` instance)*

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html

> As your needs change, you might find that your instance is over-utilized (the instance type is too small) or under-utilized (the instance type is too large). If this is the case, you can change the size of your instance. For example, if your t2.micro instance is too small for its workload, you can change it to an m3.medium instance.

`Choose Actions, select Instance State, and then choose Stop.`

I guess I couldn't find option in the UI as the instance was still running.

Comment: As you found, you have to stop the instance to change the size, but once stopped it's trivial to change your instance size.